# Organizing statuses in Redux createSlice

Tags: react-redux, logic

I'm new to Redux and have to structure my store to handle CRUD for *a* customer, all customers, and customer partners. I'm trying to understand the best way to use `createSlice` for this...do I separate concerns for all customers and single customers? Or do I combine them into a single customerSlice?

```
const initialState = {
    customerData: [],
    customerStatus: 'idle',
    allCustomerData: [],
    allCustomersStatus: 'idle',
    error: null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the difference is between `customerData` and `allCustomerData` for your particular app.

Is `customerData` just the entry of `allCustomerData` which corresponds to the current customer?  You never want to have the same information in two places, so if that's the case then you would want to store something like `currentCustomerId` and use a selector to select the data for the current customer from `allCustomerData` based on the id.

Read up on the concept of [entities](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape).  It seems like customer is an entity, and you may have others as well.

A typical setup would be to have one slice to manage customers where the state is an object of customers keyed by customer id. `status` might be a property that exists on each customer object alongside `name`, `id`, `address`, etc.